# What is the meaning of the red exclamation mark inside a triangle next to the title of the reports in Google Analytics 4 (GA4)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have set up a GA4 account for my company's business website. It was set up about 4 months ago and I have been continually seeing an exclamation mark next to the title of the reports. Not sure what that means. Even the mouse-hover info tip doesn't give any legend info specific to the exclamation mark. Can anyone help me with it please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red exclamation means that Google applied a data threshold. This could mean that the data currently shown is sampled and not available for 100% of your data.

According to [Google's help center article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630?hl=en), "When a threshold is applied to a report or exploration, the data indicator changes color. You can hover over the indicator to see more information. The indicator can also help you identify when [sampling](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192) is applied."